# Is super doing anything if so Can someone explain

Tags: java, android

I am looking through the net and finding examples of code and trying to understand them. in this one I believe super is doing nothing is that correct. in eclipe it tells me it comes from Objects class. in Java there is a tutorial.

I am trying to learn the connections between Me creating Objects into a "ArrayAdapter" into a "ListAdapter" and in the Android 4 opening template they use "ListFragment" so i would be made to belive even though i don't understand this it is corrent to learn this way of adding lists to a page for "Master Detail" selection.

links [Java tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) ::
[Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) :: [ArrayAdapter tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

I guess I just missed the boat.

```
public class Weather {
public int icon;
public String title;

public Weather(){
    super();
}

public Weather(int icon, String title) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

Comment: `super()` will call the same method in your class's parent. If your class descends from object, then calling `super()` in its constructor will do nothing because object's constructor does nothing, for example. But if you want to inherit some of your superclass's behaviour despite overriding methods this is very useful.

Comment: `super()` calls the super-classes constructor. In case of `Object` being the super-class, that does effectively do *nothing*. Some IDE's like to insert it by default, that's probably the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoking `super()` in a constructor is never necessary, because if you don't, the compiler inserts this instruction for you.

So

```
public Foo() {
    // some instructions
}
```

and

```
public Foo() {
    super();
    // some instructions
}
```

are strictly equivalent. The first thing a constructor must do is to invoke one of the superclass constructors. If you forget to do it, the compiler does it for you by inserting a `super()` call. And if the superclass doesn't have a visible no-arg constructor, you'll get a compilation error.

Invoking `super(someArguments)` is often necessary when you want (or need) to invoke a constructor of the base class that is not the no-arg constructor.

Comment: Also having no constructor at all is strictly equivalent to both those examples.

Comment: ^ It's always safer to just go ahead and put it in from the beginning, though, to avoid errors about not having a default constructor if you(or someone else) were to implement a constructor that takes arguments later down the road.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say that super() is doing nothing. It calls its super class's no-arg constructor. Even if the class inherits directly from java.lang.Object then Object's constructor is called, though it does nothing. Of course JVM optimizer will quickly eliminate such useless calls.